# requestAnimationFrame doesn't update repeatedly a react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requestanimationframe

Just want to know why my **requestAnimationFrame** doesn't update my react component repeatedly? it only returned count value the very first time,and then it ignore it.
here's the code :

```
// ----- animation.js
import React from "react";

let count = 0;
export default function Update() {
  return <>{UpdateComponents()}</>;
}

function UpdateComponents() {
  count++;

  window.requestAnimationFrame(UpdateComponents);

  return <p>count: {count}</p>;
}

// ------ index.js
// ReactDOM.render(<Update />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Update gets called when the component (re) renders.  It won't matter that UpdateComponents runs over and over, there is nothing connecting UpdateComponents to the content on your page, except for when Update executes.

Comment: Even if this worked, you wouldn't like the result. React has to do too many things between requesting a render and the DOM update being performed for you to achieve smooth animations. This is why libraries like Framer Motion, React Spring, and D3 React still do direct DOM manipulation (bypassing the React rendering process).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`requestAnimationFrame` is working as you expect, if you add a `console.log(count)` after the place where you increment `count` you'll see the value changing.

The reason it isn't showing up in your DOM is that no component is tracking the value of `count` so nothing knows that it should be re-rendered. You'll need to hook your updates into state or prop changes in order to make the component show the 'live' count.

Answer (score 0):

```
export default function Update() {
  return <>{UpdateComponents()}</>;
}
```

`<Update />` render what the first `UpdateComponents()` returned, but the return of the other `UpdateComponents()` invoked by window.requestAnimationFrame doesn't used by any Component, so `requestAnimationFrame` is working, but not impacts the content of the dom.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't rerender because it doesn't trigger the reactdom
In other for it to rerender repeatedly
Use this piece of code

```
import React,{useState} from "react";


export default function Update() {
Let [count, setCount]=useState(0)
function UpdateComponents() {

  var newcount=count + 1;
setCount(newCount)
  window.requestAnimationFrame(UpdateComponents);
UpdateComponents()
 
}
  return <><p>count: {count}</p></>
}
```

This should work perfectly